# title on disabled html input

Tags: html

Is there a way to show title on a disabled html input. When I set the disabled attribute for the input, title is not shown.

Comment: with either css or onmouseover/out events.

Comment: As of Firefox 8, the title of a disabled element is displayed upon hover.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a matter of browser because the title still shows up in Safari but not i Firefox.

Like @Prix said you'll propably have to use a JavaScript solution to make it work reliably.